# Changing log directory script IIS

Tags: powershell, permissions, acl, ntfs

I ve tried to create a code which changes the directory from default to E:\Logfiles . Additionally I need to manage there some permissions groups which should be stored in XML or just added via ACL.

Could someone please give me advice how to manage with that? 
My short code is below which should check if folder exist, go trough all servers on the farm.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$LogPath = “E:\LogFiles\”
foreach ($srv in (Get-SPServer | ? {($_.role -like "WebFrontEnd*") -or ($_.role -like "Application")}))
    {
    If(!(test-path $Logpath))
        {
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $path
        }
    foreach($site in (dir iis:\sites\*))
        {
            New-Item $LogPath\$($site.Name) -type directory
            Set-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\$($site.Name) -name logFile.directory -value “$LogPath\$($site.Name)” 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Additionally I need to make this file shareable with some AD groups, is that possible?

Comment: The above code is different than your ask. I would like to know more in details about what exactly you are trying to achieve. What are those permissions? What you wish to share to the AD groups? Is that the permission file that you wish to share? All are possible, but you have to be precise on this context. Edit your question and give the relevant code based on your ask.